# CakePHP set input form as disabled depending on certain condition

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, input

Hello I've made a form in my ctp file like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Status', array(
'div' => array('class' => 'xDiv'),
'label' => __('Status'),
'type' => 'select',
'empty' => 'Complete',//dummy
'class' => __('Status'),
'options' => $options
)); ?>
```

When a certain condition is satisfied I want my form to be disabled adding feature 'disabled' => true.
How can I do this without changing cakePHP functionality, meaning not going back to plain html and echo the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Status', array(
                                'div' => array('class' => 'xDiv'),
                                'label' => __('Status'),
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'empty' => 'Complete',//dummy
                                'class' => __('Status'),
                                'options' => $options
                                'disabled' => ($foo == $bar ? true : false)
)); ?>
```

Replacing `$foo == $bar` with whatever logic you need. Making it as verbose or condensed as you like. See: [ternary operators](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).